# Parameterization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

I am faced with the very annoying problem of finding a continuous map which will transform the unit square in to the triangle. This is a problem in topology and the map need to obey certain identifications. I am very, very stuck as to how to approach this correctly....

These are the identifications I need....
$$ (0,0) \to (1,0,0)$$
$$ (0,1) \to (1,0,0)$$
$$ (1,0) \to (0,0,1)$$
$$ (1,1) \to (0,0,1)$$
$$ (\frac{1}{2}, 1) \to (0,1,0)$$

This is just the square for the homotopic paths.

I would also really appreciate an example as to how to approach this type of problem.

Comment: What do those identifications mean?

Comment: I need to send $(0,0) \to (1,0,0)$

Comment: That's one point in the plane and another in space?

Comment: Yes, from $(0,0)$ in the plane to $(1,0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. My main goal is to find a continuous map from the unit square to the 2-simplex.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Map the square to the circle and then map the circle to the triangle.

Comment: I've thought of doing that, but I get a bit confused because of the interior of the square. Does the interior matter?